# borderTopLeftRadius and the other 3 corner radius counterparts not working

Tags: android, react-native

I was trying to round the corner of my square views but found the corner border radius props not working. I have tried all four of them(`borderTopLeftRadius`, `borderTopRightRadius`, `borderBottomLeftRadius`, `borderBottomRightRadius`), but none works. The `borderRadius` props though work fine. I am using RN 0.12 on Mac OS.

The code snippet is as below.

```
name ='Button'
style = {{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white',borderBottomLeftRadius:30, borderBottomRightRadius:30, height:75,width:345 }}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the component or your item using a View and apply the borderTopRightRadius/borderTopLeftRadius to that View with {overflow: 'hidden'}.

For Example:

```
 <View style={{overflow:'hidden', borderTopRightRadius: 20}}>
       //Your Component or Item goes here
 </View>
```

This works for me on IOS :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add borderWidth

```
style = {{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white',borderBottomLeftRadius: 30, borderBottomRightRadius:30, height: 75,width: 345, borderWidth: 1 }}
```

Comment: I tried but except for adding only a dark border around the box, it still didn't round the corner of the box. Can I know the system and RN version info for which the code above works?

Comment: you need wrap inside another ```<View />```, not in the main ```<View style={{flex:1}} />```, I believe you trying to round the corner of the main screen View

Comment: Do you mean I should do something like below?  <View> <View style = {{borderBottomLeftRadius:30}}> <Text> test <Text> </View></View>   I tried this but still corner not rounded. Can I know if your platform is Android?